# iMessage Apple script - Trying to send a message to target that can be the Full Name or Number

Tags: ios, macos, applescript, bots

I am trying to take in a target and have an if statement determine if it's a phone number or the full name. I cant seem to figure out how to find the full name from the iMessage app. Here is what I got so far and it seems to just be when the target is a noninteger.

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

    launch application "Messages"
    tell application "Messages"
        set targetService to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
        set targetPhoneNumber to "Alejandro Cervantes"
        set targetMessageToSend to "Test"
        
        if targetPhoneNumber is not integer then
            set targetName to get id of account of participant targetPhoneNumber
            set targetBuddy to participant targetPhoneNumber of targetService whose full name is targetPhoneNumber
        else
            set targetBuddy to participant targetPhoneNumber of targetService
        end if
        
        set targetMessage to targetMessageToSend
        send targetMessage to targetBuddy
        
    end tell
```

Comment: Well, one thing you have wrong is `participant` as it's not singular but plural i.e. "**participants** (list of buddy, r/o) : Other participants of this chat. This property may be specified at time of creation." and is not applicable to what you are trying to do from what I see. As to the `if targetPhoneNumber is not integer then`, how do you expect to trigger the _true_ side of that _statement_? You cannot pass `targetPhoneNumber` as an _integer_ because the _phone number_ is passed as a _string_!

Comment: Please review the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ for **Messages** in the **Library** of **Script Editor**. Press **⇧⌘L** while in **Script Editor**, or click **Library** from its **Window** menu.

Comment: Also why are you setting `set targetName to get id of account of participant targetPhoneNumber` as `targetName` is an unused _variable_ in the rest of the _script_ you show? Additionally, the first three lines of _code_ are not at all necessary if this is the extent of your _script_.